# How add const to await page.$eval in puppeteer Node.js?

Tags: constants, puppeteer, href, eval, evaluate

I want to edit href link before button click. I want to use const. I had problem with:

```
Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: dourl2 is not defined
```

My code look like this:

#1 Grab href link from button

```
    const dourl = await page.$eval("#dodaj_do_koszyka"+ link, el => el.href);
```

#2 Add '000' to link:

```
    const dourl2 = dourl + '000';
```

#3 Put changed href to button:

```
    await page.$eval("#dodaj_do_koszyka" + link, element  => element.href = '{dourl2}' );
```

How put const in this place correctly ? This method generate an error:

```
'{dourl2}'
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure `element.href = '{dourl2}'` is cited as is? `'{dourl2}'` is a string, it cannot cause  this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need to use the `args` parameters (see [docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1)):

```js
await page.$eval(
  "#dodaj_do_koszyka" + link,
  (element, url) => { element.href = url; },
  dourl2,
);
```